# Is there any way to get number of combinations of matrices exclude "equal"?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, combinations

I have width, height of matrix and range in which item can be. For example, for width = 2, height = 2 and range = 2 I have the following matrices:

```
00 10 01 00 00 11 00 10 01 10 01 01 10 11 11 11
00 00 00 10 01 00 11 10 01 01 10 11 11 01 10 11
```

But I need to consider matrices as equal if one can be obtained from other by swapping any rows or columns. So these matrices are equal:

```
10 01
00 00
```

Considering this, set of matrices will be:

```
00 10 11 10 10 01 11
00 00 00 10 01 11 11
```

And answer is 7.
Trying to solve it, I noticed that elements in row or in column remains the same, only their order changes, so I wrote script on python that make all combinations of matrices excluding "equal". Function detecting "equal" matrices works like this:

1 get arrays of sorted rows for both matrices

2 translate them to mapping array. For example [1, 0, 2] shows that row 0 in first matrix mapped to row 1 in second matrix.

3 make same steps for columns.

4 go through matrix comparing them like this:

```
if matrix1[i][j] != matrix2[rowsMapping[i]][columnsMapping[j]]:
    return False
```

5 If there is no different elements, we have "equal" matrices.

It works, but not very fast and I suspect that I'm going in wrong way. Maybe there is some combinatorics formula to solve this task?

Answer (score 0):

You want [Burnside's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma). You have a finite set $X$, the matrices of size $n\times m$ with entries in some finite set, and a group $G$, the group generated by swapping rows and columns, and you want to know the number of orbits of the action of $G$ on $X$.

Comment: OK, I have set of matrices(X), actions(G), for example above, it will be: {action which doesn't change matrix, swapping row 0 and 1, swapping column 0 and 1}, 3 actions at all. And I need to use Burnside's lemma's formula. But I don't know how to get number of Xg - fixed elements. So I should write code like this: https://pastebin.com/2U0srMc7
Stupid markup language doesn't let me to make newline.

Comment: @devalone The number of matrices fixed by a given permutation $g$ is something you should work out a formula for on paper, not in code. The whole point of using Burnside's lemma is so that you can get a formula on paper that your computer can compute easily, rather than having it brute force the problem. When $g$ only swaps rows or only swaps columns, $|X^g|$ is easy to calculate, when $g$ is more complicated it's harder, though.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941503/number-of-equivalence-classes-of-matrices-under-switching-rows-and-columns) has some further ideas. Actually I'm going to vote to close this question as a duplicate of that one, it's the same question really.