# Greatest Common Divisor in pair of cycles

Tags: combinatorics, gcd-and-lcm, permutation-cycles

In this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1941637/700855), the author says each block of $n\times m$ elements is split into $\gcd(m,n)$ distinct cycles. This seems nontrivial, how is this proven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:
$$
\gcd(m,n)=\dfrac{m\times n}{\operatorname{lcm}(m, n)}
$$

Comment: Thanks, that helped. So m*n is the total number of possible arrangements, and lcm(m,n) is the number of steps of the permutation it takes to get back to the original, which is also the number of permutations in one "equivalence class" or cycle, so to speak. So the number of cycles is m*n / lcm(m,n) which is just gcd(m,n). Does that about sum it up?

Comment: @Poseidon23 Absolutely right ;D